# Imgproc.findContours() usage

Tags: java, opencv

Iam a beginner to opencv and java. I want to learn the usage and functionalities of the method `Imgproc.findContours()`. I didn't get any source to learn it. can anybody please explain the working of the same in detail. or can anyone suggest me a suitable source to learn it.

Answer (score 4):

One example :

```
public class FindContours implements ImageFilter {

    @Override
    public Mat filter(final Mat src) {

        final Mat dst = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), src.type());
        src.copyTo(dst);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        final List<MatOfPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
        final Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(dst, points, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        return dst;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

from 
https://github.com/ahanin/opencv-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/year/opencv/demo/filters/FindContours.java

And the link of the last doc :
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a

Comment: What I wanted was not an example. I expected some documentations. Anyway thanks. I  can refer